# Mac/Eclipse CDT: How to install boost

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, boost

Mac (El Capitan)/Eclipse CDT/boost : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

A beginner question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

int main(void) {
        boost::locale::generator gen;
                    std::locale loc=gen("");
                    std::locale::global(loc);
                    std::cout.imbue(loc);
                    std::cout <<boost::locale::format("Today {1,date} at {1,time} we had run our first localization example") % time(0)
                          <<std::endl;
}
```

On building this code in Eclipse I get:

```
    Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
    /usr/local/bin/g++-5 -L/Users/sam/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib -o "cpp-test-1"  ./calc-1.o ./test-1.o   
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "boost::locale::base_message_format<char>::id", referenced from: ...
```

There are some other questions on SO regarding this error. As far as I understand the problem is caused by different stdlibs (libc++ and libstdc++) used by the compiler and the boost library.
First I installed boost from macports, then with homebrew and followed this tutorial (and compiled boost with ./b2 and g++-5):

http://qiita.com/misho/items/0c0b3ca25bb8f62aa681#install-boost-for-gnu-compilers

It didn’t work.

My settings in Properties/C/C++ Build:

```
    Linker
    Command: /usr/local/bin/g++-5
    All Options: -L/Users/sam/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib -std=c++0x -I -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0
    Libs: /Users/sam/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib

    Compiler
    Command: /usr/local/bin/g++-5
    All Options: -std=c++0x -I/Users/sam/boost_1_60_0 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0
    Includes: /Users/sam/boost_1_60_0


    lib$ otool -L libboost_locale.dylib
    libboost_locale.dylib:
    libboost_locale.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libboost_system.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/5/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.21.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1225.1.1)
    /usr/local/lib/gcc/5/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

Any idea what’s wrong with my boost installation?

Answer (score 0):

Now it works. Just added option -lboost_locale to the command line pattern in Properties/C++ Build/MacOs X C++ Linker:

```
    ${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS} -std=c++11 -lboost_locale
```